# docker-compose mysql - port not bound locally

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have a problem with a docker compose configuration. I just want to create an mysql+pma config. This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    hostname: db
    image: mysql
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

The problem is that the mysql server is not listening towards port 3306 - as you can see here:

```
root@db:/# netstat -pln 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:36112        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:48093        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
```

Any idea how I can set this up properly - it seems that something is wrong with the mysql config, but all examples within the internet which I have found do not have this problem :-/

Cheers
Dennis

I also checked the port via nectat - also without success :-(

```
root@db:/# nc -zvw10 127.0.0.1 3306
localhost [127.0.0.1] 3306 (?) : Connection refused
```

The docker ps command instead is presenting the proper port config:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS                               NAMES
60ee3ca7fbd0   mysql                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes            0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysqlnew_db_1
```

Comment: Why do you have this in there ? `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

Comment: This was mentioned in the official documentation. But also disabling this and restarting via docker compose does not help :-/ To restart I used:



sudo docker-compose down --remove-orphans
sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate

Comment: Have you checked MySQL container logs? That might give you some insights.

Comment: @Anton: Many thanks!!! It was just a timing issue! the " ready for connections" entry in the db pod logs was missing - and after waiting 1-2minutes it was ready to go. Now everything works as expected - I was just to Impatient :-D